# Azure IoT Hub GetNextAsTwinAsync after query execution goes Exception

Tags: c#, sql, .net, azure-iot-hub

I'm trying to query devices into my Azure IoT Hub:

```
var query = registry.CreateQuery("SELECT * FROM devices where statusUpdateTime<=" + (rightnowUTC-tenMinAgoUTC ));
        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            var page = await query.GetNextAsTwinAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Devices con aggiornamento negli ultimi dieci minuti");
            foreach (var twin in page)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Device id: " + twin.DeviceId + ", Connection state: " + twin.ConnectionState + ", Status: " +
                 twin.Status + ", Last activity time: " + twin.LastActivityTime + ", Status updated time: "+twin.StatusUpdatedTime);
            }
        }
```

I checked the query object itself and let the while cycle being executed.

Once it goes to the "GetNextAsTwinSync" will be raised this exception:

```
(Inner Exception #0) System.ArgumentException: {"Message":"ErrorCode:ArgumentInvalid;BadRequest","ExceptionMessage":"Tracking ID:b862e066a6944c9caf8f726aae82f80d-G:12-TimeStamp:07/10/2019 11:55:01"}
       at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.HttpClientHelper.ExecuteAsync(HttpClient httpClient, HttpMethod httpMethod, Uri requestUri, Func`3 modifyRequestMessageAsync, Func`2 isMappedToException, Func`3 processResponseMessageAsync, IDictionary`2 errorMappingOverrides, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.HttpClientHelper.PostAsync[T](Uri requestUri, T entity, IDictionary`2 errorMappingOverrides, IDictionary`2 customHeaders, MediaTypeHeaderValue customContentType, ICollection`1 customContentEncoding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.HttpRegistryManager.ExecuteQueryAsync(String sqlQueryString, Nullable`1 pageSize, String continuationToken, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Query.GetNextAsync(QueryOptions options)
       at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Query.GetAndCastNextResultAsync[T](QueryResultType type, QueryOptions options)
       at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Query.GetNextAsTwinAsync(QueryOptions options)
       at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Query.GetNextAsTwinAsync()
```

Answer (score 0):

I do recommend read the [IoT Hub query language for device and module twins, jobs, and message routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-query-language)

Your query string is wrong and that's the reason for *System.ArgumentException*.

Use the following query string:

```
string querystring = $"SELECT * FROM devices where statusUpdateTime <= '{(DateTime.UtcNow - TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)).ToString("o")}'";
```

Note, that the ISO 8601 formats is strongly recommended for datetime data type.

Comment: Hi Roman, please could you explain me, besides the ISO format, what is the real error?

You wrote the query with the same comparative types (timespan) as me, but... What's the real error I did?

Comment: The first, the query string must follow the T-SQL expression, so the datetime value must be as a text using a single quotes. Secondly, the correct datetime format such as ISO 8601 e.g.  *2019-07-11T11:13:38.3052721Z*